# SQL with Left Join showing values that are zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a SQL query setup but I want it to ignore 0's in the `min_on_hand` column, and I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work

```
SELECT  
    sku_master.sku, 
    sku_master.description, 
    sku_master.min_on_hand,
    sku_master.max_on_hand, 
    x.total_qty_on_hand 
FROM 
    [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         sku_master.sku, 
         sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand 
     FROM 
         [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory] 
     JOIN 
         [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
     WHERE 
         sku_master.min_on_hand > 0 
     GROUP BY 
         sku_master.sku) x ON sku_master.sku = x.sku;
```

Comment: do you mean you dont want to show records with min_on_hand = 0 ?

Comment: It looks like your only LEFT JOIN ing them if they are > 0, rather than filtering the final results. You could try an INNER JOIN, or put the WHERE clause on your original query instead of the nested SELECT.

Comment: Your WHERE sku_master.min_on_hand > 0 is in the sub query.  Is it supposed to be in the main query?

Comment: You are joining the table against itself - the subquery has the check for min_on_hand > 0, but the outer query does not. Try adding " WHERE sku_master.min_on_hand > 0" to the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I needed to put the WHERE at the end of the query. Doing so fixed my issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, filtering on `min_on_hand` in the subquery has no effect - you'll still be returned the values in `sku_master`, but they just won't include any of the data from `x`.

If you move the check to the main query then you will not see any records where `min_on_hand` = 0

```
SELECT  
    sku_master.sku, 
    sku_master.description, 
    sku_master.min_on_hand,
    sku_master.max_on_hand, 
    x.total_qty_on_hand 
FROM 
    [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         sku_master.sku, 
         sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand 
     FROM 
         [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory] 
     JOIN 
         [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
     GROUP BY 
         sku_master.sku) x ON sku_master.sku = x.sku
WHERE 
    sku_master.min_on_hand > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    sku_master.sku, 
    sku_master.description, 
    sku_master.min_on_hand,
    sku_master.max_on_hand, 
    x.total_qty_on_hand 
FROM 
    [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         sku_master.sku, 
         sum(location_inventory.qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand 
     FROM 
         [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory] 
     JOIN 
         [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] ON location_inventory.sku = sku_master.sku
     GROUP BY 
         sku_master.sku) x ON sku_master.sku = x.sku;
     WHERE 
         sku_master.min_on_hand > 0
```

Moving the WHERE to the end of the statement fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct answer but why the join in the derived table

```
SELECT  
    sku_master.sku, 
    sku_master.description, 
    sku_master.min_on_hand,
    sku_master.max_on_hand, 
    x.total_qty_on_hand 
 FROM [FCI].dbo.[sku_master] 
 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, 
                    sum(qty_on_hand) as total_qty_on_hand 
               FROM [FCI].[dbo].[location_inventory] 
              GROUP BY sku ) x 
   ON sku_master.sku = x.sku
WHERE sku_master.min_on_hand > 0
```

Comment: Because I am new and that's how I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this query.  It returns an inventory summary, for all records where the minimum on hand quantity needs to exceed 0.

`/* Left join sku_master  */

```
    SELECT        sku_master.sku, sku_master.description, sku_master.min_on_hand, 
                  sku_master.max_on_hand, 
                  location_inventory.qty_on_hand AS total_qty_on_hand
    FROM          sku_master LEFT OUTER JOIN location_inventory 
                    ON sku_master.sku = location_inventory.sku
    GROUP BY sku_master.sku, sku_master.description, 
                  sku_master.min_on_hand, sku_master.max_on_hand, 
                  location_inventory.qty_on_hand
    HAVING        (sku_master.min_on_hand > 0)`
```